# How do I get a java JNA call to a DLL to get data returned in parameters?

Tags: java, delphi, jna

I have this java test

```
package ftct;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import java.util.Date;

public class LibFTCT {


public LibFTCT() {
 }
 public interface LibFTCTLib extends StdCallLibrary {
          LibFTCTLib INSTANCE = (LibFTCTLib) Native.loadLibrary(
             "FTCTLib", LibFTCTLib.class);
      int a(int x);
      int DoCommand(int Command, int Param);
    int GetDataRecord(int RecordNum, int StreamNum, Date ReadingTime,
   double AIN1, double AIN2, double AIN3, double AIN4);

 }
}
```

It calls a Delphi DLL. If put the parameters as var in Delphi the Java crashes. Otherwise they are read only.

I want GetDataRecord to return data in RecordNum etc. How do I do this in java?

Comment: I'm not a JNA expert, but since var parameters are reference parameters, I don't think that the Java side of things can declare and use primitives.

Comment: What are you hoping will happen to that Date parameter?

Comment: @David   I have found some code which suggests using                  Date date = new Date((long)(ReadingTimeRef.getValue()*1000.0));
       ReadingRecords[RecNo-1].ReadingTime = date; but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the parameters as special types that convey the fact that they are passed by reference. So if the Delphi parameters are like this:

```
procedure Foo(var i: Integer; var d: Double);
```

you would map that to a Java function like this:

```
void Foo(IntByReference i, DoubleByReference d);
```

And to call the function:

```
IntByReference iref = new IntByReference();
DoubleByReference dref = new DoubleByReference();
INSTANCE.Foo(iref, dref);
int i = iref.getValue();
double d = dref.getValue():
```

This is all covered in some detail in the [documentation](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/ByRefArguments.md):

> **Using ByReference Arguments**
>
> When a function accepts a pointer-to-type argument you can use one of
>   the ByReference types to capture the returned value, or subclass your
>   own. For example:
>
> ```
> // Original C declaration
> void allocate_buffer(char **bufp, int* lenp);
>
> // Equivalent JNA mapping
> void allocate_buffer(PointerByReference bufp, IntByReference lenp);
>
> // Usage
> PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
> IntByReference iref = new IntByReference();
> lib.allocate_buffer(pref, iref);
> Pointer p = pref.getValue();
> byte[] buffer = p.getByteArray(0, iref.getValue());
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you could use a Java array with a single element of the
>   desired type, but the ByReference convention better conveys the intent
>   of the code. The Pointer class provides a number of accessor methods
>   in addition to getByteArray() which effectively function as a typecast
>   onto the memory.
>
> Type-safe pointers may be declared by deriving from the PointerType
>   class.