# Java JNA Mapping in Delphi Dll function

Tags: java, delphi, dll, mapping, jna

How do i map this function with JNA:

**Delphi Dll Function Code:**

```
function send_command (const command : byte; var size : byte; var data : pbyte) : integer; stdcall external 'comunication.dll';
```

Use example in Delphi Example Program:

**send_command (cmdCLOCK_ADJUST, tam, pb);**

Where:

```
const 
    cmdCLOCK_ADJUST = $18;

var
   tam : byte;
   pb, p : pbyte;

begin
   ...
    tam = 7;
    p:= pb;
       for i:= 1 to tam do
          begin
            p^:= Dados [i];
            inc (p)
          end;
    send_command (cmdCLOCK_ADJUST, tam, pb);
    freemem (pb);
   ...
end
```

The int value that is returned can be 0 for Error or 1 for right execution;

My suggestion is:

**JNA Java Function Code:**

```
int send_command(byte command, byte size, byte[] data);
```

The problem is that the function of the dll returns 0. I also tried other Datatypes, but it hasn't worked jet. I think the problem is that the dll function can't write to the parameter data.

Comment: The `data` parameter is the problem. the callee passes a pointer out? Really. Please show sample calling code in Pascal, or the documentation.

Comment: I added a example, David.

Comment: That doesn't add any more information. We cannot see what the types are. Who allocates the memory. And so on. You aren't going to be able to make progress until you can work out the semantics of the interface. Knowing the types is not enough. Since `data` is a var parameter of type `pbyte`, one assumes that the callee allocates the memory. Your code contradicts that. On the face of it, the problem is actually with the Delphi code which is wrong.

Comment: Will I need to know what types of variables used in the dll code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Delphi code is actually wrong.

The `size` parameter appears to be a means to pass the length of the data from the caller to the callee. As such it should not be a `var` parameter.

The `data` parameter appears to be a pointer to a buffer allocated by the caller. Again, that should not be a `var` parameter. Just a plain `PByte`, passed by value.

Which would make the Delphi code be like this:

```
function send_command(const command: Byte; size: Byte; data: PByte): Integer; 
  stdcall external 'comunication.dll';
```

And then the Delphi code would match your Java code.

Of course, I've had to make a number of guesses to write this answer. Guesses based on my experience of such problems, but guesses all the same. The real lesson that you should take away from this is that an interface is not specified by the types of its parameters. You also need to specify the semantics of the parameter passing.

So, when you have a `PByte` paramerer, is that a pointer to a single byte, or a pointer to an array? If the latter, how large is the array. And so on. You need to specify all of this information to define an interface.

If you really cannot change the DLL, then you'll need to pass the `size` and `data` parameters by reference, even though they appear to have value semantics. This answer covers passing by reference in JNA: [How do I get a java JNA call to a DLL to get data returned in parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380916/how-do-i-get-a-java-jna-call-to-a-dll-to-get-data-returned-in-parameters/17381399#17381399)

Comment: Thank you David . The problem is that the DLL is already up and running with an application also developed in Delphi and was asked to develop a Java applet to communicate with this DLL. From what you told me , you need to make several changes to the dll to work properly.

Comment: I think the main point is that you need to work out what the interface is first. You are getting well ahead of yourself. If you have to call this interface then it's easy enough to pass params by ref with JNA, but it's more work that you should have to do. Is it really not possible to get the DLL developer to see sense?

Comment: David, I tried to pass parameters by reference as the example that gave me, however , even the return of the function is zero. For lack of experience in this my subject, I believe be doing something wrong . See : JNA Mapping - int send_command(byte command, ByteByReference size, PointerByReference data);

Comment: Clearly you are doing something wrong. I answered the question you asked. I don't want to get into an extended debugging session. You need to learn some very basic debugging skills. Don't debug the actual function. Start with a dummy function to prove that you can send the data back and forth. Anyway, you still have not addressed the main issue I raised. Until you do that I don't see much hope.

Comment: David, I can´t modify the Delphi DLL, but I get the result 1 like function response using ByteByReference and PointerByReference ... However, I can´t view and get ther result from variable "data". I tried to use pointer (getValue), but not worked. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: As I said, until you address the main issue, I have nothing more to say.